# Voyager - Admin Panel Package for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I am having problem on `laravel` - Voyager admin panel package installation command. When I put this command `php artisan voyager:install` a notification show on terminal:

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
>     There are no commands defined in the "storage" namespace.

After this `php artisan serve`command I found my admin panel but its show a problem, following screen are showing after submitting log in by default password.

[image: laravel Voyager template error screen]

[GitHub repository for this Package/Doc](https://github.com/momin-ctg/voyager)

Comment: Issue has been created on GitHub https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/84

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this instead of `php artisan voyager:install`:

1. `composer.phar dump-autoload`
2. `php artisan db:seed`

This may help you.

Dont forget to add

```
TCG\Voyager\VoyagerServiceProvider::class,
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
```

into your `config/app.php` file in the 'providers' => [ array

Comment: Its all about **php** and **laravel** versioning problem for me ! I ensure the both latest version, followed by the author instruction and i am done . Thanks  [Advaith](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6349060/advaith)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably installing this on a version of Laravel 5.2 or earlier. Laravel 5.2 does not have the artisan command to create a symlink. Can you check your Laravel version :)

Solution also posted here: https://devdojo.com/forums/discussion/php/voyager-voyager-e-for-laravel-admin-panel-package-for-laravel

Thanks.

Comment: Just ensure we have to installed **php version 5.6.4** and **laravel 5.3+** on your machine , then follow  instruction from voyager [GitHub](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager) doc. I had same problem ......... too! Now i fix it .


[composer.json screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM2jX.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you instaled Voyager on laravel 5.3, you need to add 
    TCG\Voyager\VoyagerServiceProvider::class,
to your config/app.php at your PROVIDER and it will work.

Comment: Thanks @Tudor Problem fixing Complete.